# Mouse Cursor Duplicating With One of the Cursors Stuck in Upper Left of Page

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm having an issue where my mouse cursor is duplicating; one of the cursors seems to be stuck at the top left-hand side of the screen, but the other cursor moves around normally.

Take a look:

http://hugginz.com/nacimiento

I built this site a while ago, and never had this issue before.  Simply trying to stick it up on my own site, using the same code as the site was using when it was up, with no changes.

The cursor is set as:

```
html, body {
cursor: url(SpermCursorWhiteFinal.png), auto;}
```

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks fine in chrome.  Which browser shows the issue?

Comment: I'm seeing it in Chrome and Firefox.  You're not seeing a duplicate, with one stuck in the upper left hand corner?

Comment: Not on chrome on mac or windows.  Nor on firefox in windows or mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue isolated to only one machine - not sure why, but not able to duplicate on any other machines.